# Calling button with jQuery won't receive JSON response

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm new to JSON, but what I'm trying to do, is when I click my button on my HTML page, the console should display the content.

This works when I'm NOT wrapping the `$.getJSON` in a function but I can't figure out what the problem is when I'm calling it from a button.

I want to keep the call asynchronous, so I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or if there's a better way.

Heres my JS code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://mysite', function(data) {
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++){
          console.log(data.files[i].title);
          var path = data.files[i].path;
          console.log(path);
          document.getElementById("getMedia").innerHTML = 'https://mysite' + path;
          }
        });
      });
});
```

This is the HTML

```
   <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="getfiles">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

I also tried changing the call of the click of the button to `$("#getfiles").click(function()` but that did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that your page is submitting and refreshing. Try adding the `event` parameter to your function call and then run the method `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default *submission* behavior of the browser.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("button").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // <-- Add this line

        $.getJSON('https://mysite', function(data) {
            /* ... */
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the button `type="submit"` this actually submits the form. The normal behavior then is that the pages refresh. Remove the `type="submit"` like below.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="getfiles">Submit</button>
```

In this case, you can leave the click handler as it.